# Check Excel has password and prevent Prompt C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have looked on the internet and on this site as to how to check if file has a password.  The problem is how to prevent Excel prompting you for a correct password.  I see there's HasPassword but it seems to me that property is only useable when the sheet has been opened.

```
try {
oWrkBk = oApp.Workbooks.Open(sFile, Password: "");
}
catch { /* has password */
```

But the problem is, the Excel open a prompt window which I don't want.  If I can't open it, I'll skip it and close the Excel window down.

Comment: I believe if an Excel file is requesting a password when it is opened, it's because the file is encrypted. Wouldn't ignoring that become a breach of security (Based from: `The problem is how to prevent Excel prompting you for a correct password`? (Or did I completely miss the question)

Comment: The idea is that we're given an excel file to be processed, if the file is encrypted then we don't process it.  Yes, how to prevent Excel prompt for the correct password.

Comment: Have you tried using a library like EPPlus instead of Interop? That's a problem with Interop. If you just open it as an XML file then if it can't open it will just fail, but there's no prompt. Then you get the added benefit that nearly anything else you want to do with that spreadsheet is easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless `OleDb` is out of the question, you'll be able to use that to determine whether or not the file has a password based on if an exception is thrown.

Example code to show:

```
//using System.Data.OleDb;
private static void OpenMyExcel()
{
    string filePath = "C:\\users\\me\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx";
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0\"");

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        //Do stuff
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //has a password
    }
}
```

Which could be changed to a simple check method (sorry for amateur code):

```
//using System.Data.OleDb;
private static bool HaveAPass(string filePath)
{
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0\"");

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        connection.Close(); //if it reaches this point, there is no password
        return false;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //has a password
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I keep getting Provider is not installed but I have installed the 64 Bit version.

Comment: @MiscellaneousUser , Interop DLLs seem to only be available in 32bit versions ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502434/solve-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-issue-without-installing-microsoft-ac)). You can try changing your build configuration to 32bit instead of "Any CPU" or "64Bit"

Comment: Thx for coming back on this one Symon.  I found out by asking another question I had to turn off 'Prefer 32 Bit' Option which I wasn't aware of.  I ended up using the second method.

Comment: Is there any other solution to check and open a file without using OleDbConnection?
Or is there any way to use OleDbConnection without installing driver on local machine because it is nervous to install this driver on all our customers machine?

Comment: @AdemElAwity , I haven't looked into it or even attempted to open an Excel without using an OleDbConnection. If they have Excel installed already, then this solution should work. It may be worth looking into EPPlus or ClosedXML and see if they have anything that covers this.